# How to reformulate a question?

Tags: support, editing, questions

If a better formulation for a question is reached should the question be deleted and asked again together with copying the already given answers or just edited?

Answer (score 5):

If it is substantially the same question then it should be edited.

If the existing answers apply then it is substantially the same question.